# Running NGinX with SSL on Docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, https, dockerfile

I am trying to run NGinX in a docker container and access it over HTTPS. The container starts and works fine on the port 80 but fails on 443. Please help!

Here are the steps I followed:

Default.conf

```html
server {
  listen       443;
  server_name  localhost;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
  
  ssl_protocols         TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  #ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
  #ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
  #ssl_ecdh_curve auto;
  #ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_cache none;
  ssl_session_tickets off; 
  
  #ssl_stapling on; 
  #ssl_stapling_verify on;
  #ssl_stapling_verify off; 
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
 
  keepalive_timeout     1200;
  client_body_timeout   1200;
  client_header_timeout 1200;
  
  proxy_read_timeout 300;
  client_max_body_size 200M;
  client_body_buffer_size 200M;
  proxy_request_buffering off;
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
  location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  ssi on;
}
```

Docker file is

```html
FROM nginx

ENV LANG C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y \
    openssl

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
CMD ["echo", "Moved conf files"]
ADD cert.sh /cert.sh
RUN chmod a+x /cert.sh
CMD ["echo", "Added cert.sh"]
RUN ./cert.sh;
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I am building docker image with `docker build -t nginx .` Running the container with `docker run --name mynginx4 -P -d nginx`

I can see `/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt` and `/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key` are present in the container. But when I curl I get this error

```html
BANL151bc2453:docker-nginx-ssl-secure pgupta14$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
a2dc5dd90ef0        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   48 seconds ago      Up 35 seconds       0.0.0.0:32817->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32816->443/tcp   mynginx4
```

```html
curl https://localhost:32816
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:32816
```

Output of curl -vvv

```html
curl https://localhost:32816 -vvv
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:32816/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 32816 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:32816 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:32816
```

In the output of curl -vvv, I see it is using /etc/ssl/cert.pem. Shouldn't it be using my certificates which are present at /etc/nginx/ssl/?

Comment: Can you do `curl -vvv` and post the output? Also maybe worth trying `curl -k` which disables certificate validation.

Comment: `BANL151bc2453:docker-nginx-ssl-secure$ curl localhost:32816 -k
curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you would like to delete the post, kindly click the delete button underneath the question.